# When to close the InputStream?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using Vaadin and I need to create a link to download a PDF file.
However, I need to close the InputStream. But if I close it when the user clicks to download the PDF file it is closed and throws an Exception. Where the correct place to close it?

```
File file = new File("f:\\10041328370.pdf");
Anchor a;
try{    
    InputStream is= new FileInputStream(file);          
    StreamResource res = new StreamResource("10041328370.pdf", () -> is );
    
    a = new Anchor(res, "click here to download");
    a.getElement().setAttribute("download", "downloaded-other-name.pdf");
    add(a);
    
    is.close(); //if close here, when the user to click in the anchor, we will get the error: Stream Closed.                

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage);
}
```

Comment: The way I understand the documentation (without knowing about Vaadin at all), you should not close it yourself, because you should not be opening it yourself. `StreamResource` takes an `InputStreamFactory` as its second argument. You should **there** provide Vaadin with the logic to find the stream (`() -> new FileInputStream(xxx)`) and Vaadin gets to decide when to call this factory, which is to say vaadin decides when the file gets opened, and therefore decides when it should be closed. This seems the only reasonnable approach given the method signatures. But that's an educated guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to close the InputStream. Providing the `StreamResource` an `InputStreamFactory` will call your factory to create an fresh input stream and will always close it for you (see `com.vaadin.flow.server.StreamResource.Pipe#accept` using *try-with-resources*).

But the problem here is, that you are providing a "constant" factory, that always returns the same IS. So the second download will now fail on the closed IS.  You should actually implement the factory like a real factory and always return a new IS.

E.g.

```java
StreamResource res = new StreamResource("10041328370.pdf", () -> 
    new FileInputStream(file));
```

Answer (score -3):

You should probably initialize the InputStream outside of your try catch statement. The scope of the stream is solely inside the try block, so closing it where you need to (outside of that block) is impossible since it no longer exists. Initialize it perhaps after you initialize your file:

```
File file = new File("f:\\10041328370.pdf");
InputStream is= new FileInputStream(file);  
Anchor a;
try{            
    StreamResource res = new StreamResource("10041328370.pdf", () -> is );
    
    a = new Anchor(res, "click here to download");
    a.getElement().setAttribute("download", "downloaded-other-name.pdf");
    add(a);
    
    is.close(); //if close here, when the user to click in the anchor, we will get the error: Stream Closed.               
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage);
}
```

It may be good to move the StreamResource as well.

EDIT: To answer your question, it's less about where you close the stream and more about where you open it. Close it wherever you're done taking input.